# Line-up css elements side-by-side

Tags: html, css

I have the following thing :

**HTML:**

```
<li class="left">elem1</li>  <li class="right">elem2</li>
<li class="left">elem3</li>  <li class="right">elem4</li>
```

**CSS:**

```
li.left
{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}

li.right
{
    width:50%;
    float:right;
}
```

Unfortunately, `elem1` is not lined-up with `elem2`, and so the same goes for 3 and 4.
elem (1,2,3,4) is composed of :

```
<div>
  <h1>...</h1>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

and can have many different sizes, but I still do want them to be lined-up. 
Any idea how can I resolved this by keeping the same structure (no `<table>` tag).

EDIT :
This is how it looks like :

[image: Not lined-up correctly]

Thanks.

Comment: probably with `li { display: inline-block; width: 50%; }` and you can remove the floats

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7cnu33ex/ They appear to be lined up in this example. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yupe, they are lined up. Can you explain your meaning of lined up?

Comment: do you mean this?http://fiddle.jshell.net/wm09n46L/

Comment: @Harry if he mean that then why he would have given 50% as width

Comment: well OP question is a little unclear,  elem1 is not lined-up with elem2. Also I haven't said if thats the answer. I'm simply trying to get clarification. @ShoaibChikate

Comment: Can you tell me what is full form of OP? I encounter this short form many times here.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate Original Poster

Comment: You can't have p tag inside h1!!!

Comment: Well, see my edits to have a better idea of what I was meaning

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky, your suggestion removes the bullet points because of `display: inline-block;` . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you don't say as much in your question I'm guessing that you are having a problem with aligning floats of different heights. See this graphic:

[image: misaligned floats]

The height of elem1 means that the other elements end up floating next to it rather than below.

To remedy this you should unify how they are floated and **clear the floats**:

```
li.left{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    clear:left; 
}

li.right{
    width:50%;
    float:left; /* <- even the right elems should be floated left */
    clear:right;
}
```

[image]

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/62rv2yg9/1/

#### However...

Floats are simply annoying to work with. It may well be better to use inline-blocks:

```css
ul {list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0; border-bottom:2px solid #aaa;}
ul li{
    box-sizing: border-box; /* http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/*/
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    padding:10px;
    vertical-align:top;
    border-top:2px solid #aaa;
}
ul li h1 {margin:0; font-size:16px; color:blue;}
ul li p {margin:0;}
```

```html
<ul><!--
 note. no whitespace between elements (http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)
--><li><h1>elem1</h1><p>Lorem ispum</p></li><!--
--><li><h1>elem1</h1><p>Lorem ispum aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Donec sed odio dui.</p></li><!--
--><li><h1>elem1</h1><p>Lorem ispum curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Donec sed odio dui.</p></li><!--
--><li><h1>elem1</h1><p>Lorem ispum</p></li>
</ul>
```